# C# Union vs Contains for lists of continuous data

Tags: c#, contains, unions

I'm having some trouble finding answers to a question I have about some code specific to what i'm working on and I cannot seem to find some documentation on how Union works at it's core mechanics in C#. So the problem is this.

I have a set of data that works similar to this example:

```
     object[] someMainTypeArray = new object [n];
     List<object> objList2 = new List<object>();
     foreach ( object obj in someMainTypeArray ) {
        List<object> objList1 = new List<object>() { "1","2","3" };
        //each obj has a property that will generate a list of data
        //objList1 is the result of the data specific to obj
        //some of this data could be duplicates
        //Which is better, this:
        foreach ( object test in objList1 ) {
           if ( !objList2.Contains( test ) ) {
              objList2.Add( test );
           }
        }
        //or this:
        objList2 = objList2.Union( objList1 ).ToList();
        //Also, assume this has to happen anywhere from 0 to 60 times per second
     }
```

Is it more efficient to let Union do all the work? Or is it better to compare each element using Contains?

If No for both, what is the best way to populate unique lists using the least amount of processing time possible?

Efficiency is key for this. Also, this is not homework, or anything work related, just learning related.

The lists are continuous at runtime in the way that they are eventually wiped clean and repopulated. The changes in the lists are used to make decisions based on whether or not the final result lists which are all similar to this example, are used to come up with a final list and if that list is empty, its a fail condition, and if that list is not empty, its a success condition.

Here's a snippet of the code in question for one of the lists created:

```
     Player.ClearMoves();
     List<Pair<BoardLocation, BoardLocation>> attacking = new List<Pair<BoardLocation, BoardLocation>>();
     foreach ( ChessPiece p in Board[this.Player.Opponent] ) {
        if ( p.TheoryMove( this.Location ) ) {
           foreach ( Pair<BoardLocation , BoardLocation> l in Utility.GetLocations( p.Location , this.Location ) ) {
              if ( !attacking.Contains( l ) ) {
                 attacking.Add( l );
              }
           }
        }
     }
     if ( attacking.Count < 1 ) {
        return false;
     }
```

Comment: If you use List<object> instead of Hashset<object> then Union() **may** (probably) be more efficient. If you do it _by yourself_ using an hashset then you will gain little bit in efficiency (over Union) but...I'd do it only when it's a **measured** performance issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the `Enumerable.Union` implementation in the [reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L728).

This is how it works:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Union<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second) {
    if (first == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("first");
    if (second == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("second");
    return UnionIterator<TSource>(first, second, null);
}

static IEnumerable<TSource> UnionIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
{
    Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in first)
        if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;
    foreach (TSource element in second)
        if (set.Add(element)) yield return element;
}
```

As you can see, `Union` will iterate through both enumerables and yield objects from those sources. Like all Linq methods, it will not create a list but work as a generator function. The list will only be created when you call `.ToList()`.

In order to avoid duplicates, it will use a `Set` and try to add an element before yielding it. If the addition to the set is successful, then the element was not already in there, so it can be yielded.

Note that sets are very efficient for looking up whether an element exists in it. They provide a item lookup in amortized constant time. So this is definitely more efficient than your `objList2.Contains` which will need to iterate through the list over and over to figure whether each element exists in it.

Also note that `Union` is built to maintain the order of the input enumerables. If you do not need that, then you can skip this completely and just use a `Set` in the first place. This is especially good if you plan on adding new items to the same target set all the time since it reuses the structure:

```
HashSet<object> set = new HashSet<object>();

foreach (…)
{
    List<object> objList1 = …

    // expand the set with the items from `objList1`
    set.UnionWith(objList1);
}
```

It would be even better if you avoided creating `objList1` in the first place and just added your items to the set directly—if that is possible for your use case.

Comment: I see, I seen this code but, i was not sure what this meant specifically. But, even so is it efficient to do multiple unions and then return a list at the end? or is there a way to combine lists that is more efficient?

Comment: The only reason I didn't show my code is because there might be something like 120 lines of code related to the task.

Comment: if you want to do multiple unions, it's probably better to do a custom method that uses a single set for all unions and loop over alla lists to add elements into the set.

Comment: The reason it's not good to do multiple unions to combine N lists, consider that would require N - 1 unions, and each union would lead to iteration through both lists inputs, which would make the whole operation O(N^2).

Comment: Yeah, if you want to avoid recreating as many structures as possible. So if you need to union many things, use a set as shown in my last example. If you need to maintain order, use a single set and a single list and add items to both (to the list only if it wasn’t in the set yet—just like the Union implementation).

Comment: I'm going to try use a hashset I think, Theres a lot of stuff that happens. It's a replica chess game and my checkmate implementation is really inefficient and anything I can do to make it less insane is great.  I refuse to look at example of checkmate implementations but, what I have currently is a full game, just I want to make it more efficient. The checkmates are just lists populated over and over. I moved the code into unity and when pieces are being moved, some of this code is executed a bit consistently. Maybe that will enlighten the issue a bit.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [reference source for the LINQ extensions](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,577032c8811e20d3) (search for `UnionIterator`) you will see that `Union` works internally by using a `Set<T>` to track which items have been enumerated over. Unfortunately, `Set<T>` is an internal class to the library so you can't use it directly. But there is a similar collection called `HashSet<T>` that you might use.

Probably one of the main inefficiencies in your implementation is you're creating a new list for `objList2` in each iteration of your outer loop. That will trigger iterations and memory allocations each time. Since you're building the list up through nested loops I would recommend doing one of the following things:

1. Add everything to a `List<T>` and use `.Distinct` when you're done to filter out duplicates. This approach also uses the `Set<T>` internal class, but unlike chaining multiple calls to `Union` it will only use a single `Set` to build the unique list.
2. Use a `HashSet<T>` to build a collection that always has a unique list of items in it.

Comment: This implementation lacks a lot of my detail. The thing only that is created outright is the function used to generate each new list, the list that is being populated is already instantiated at this time, so is the "mainobject" that governs everything.

Comment: It's hard for me to comment on anything other than the code that's in the question. I'm looking at the line `objList2 = objList2.Union( objList1 ).ToList();`. This creates a new list each iteration.

Comment: This is how it is specifically for the list thats inside the loop. The lists that start outside are unchanging for the most part, they may lose elements or gain elements but never be reinitialized.

Comment: Not according to the code in the question. `objList2` is initialized outside the loop but each iteration through that loop it is overwritten with a new list that contains the contents of the previous list plus any new unique values from `objList1`.

Comment: I put the actual code in question, in the main question, have a look at that instead.